# AccountKit is being depreciated

Tags: account-kit

As AccountKit is being depreciated on September 9, 2019, Im just using the email verification, is there a good alternative or do I have to start building my own?

Thanks!!

Depreciation timeline:
September 9, 2019: Account Kit will stop integrating with new apps. Existing integrations will continue to function normally.

December 9, 2019: If you’re using SMS as a means to verify phone numbers, the daily SMS limit will be reduced to a maximum of 1,000 messages per app ID per day.

March 9, 2020: Account Kit will no longer be available for developers and partners.

June 2020: Developers and partners will have until this date to retrieve data and information from the Facebook platform unless they initiate deletion before the deprecation, in which case their data will be retrievable for 30 days before being deleted from our system.

Comment: What is your purpose of use Account Kit?

Comment: Verifying emails and providing authentication without collecting passwords

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Firebase Authentication(https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/). there is some alternatives feature of Firebase Auth:

- Email and password-based authentication
- Federated identity provider integration (sign via Google, Facebook, Twitter, or GitHub)
- Phone number authentication
- Custom auth system integration
- Anonymous auth

You can check the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/?) to learn more

Comment: True, firebase seems to be the best option, but I decided to build my own just in case they decided to change their mind as facebook did lol